# net_device get_stats function, how to use?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

this is how the function looks like:

```
  struct net_device_stats* (*get_stats)(struct net_device *dev);
```

I simply need to call this function in my code and get it's results in a `net_device_stats` struct I declared earlier. Can anyone give a simple implementation code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** a function. Its the declaration of a **function pointer** `get_stats` which points to a function which receives a pointer to the structure `net_device` and returns a pointer to a structure of type `net_device_stats`

Here is one use case

```
struct net_device *dev;
struct net_device_stats *device;

device = get_stats(dev);
```

**EDIT** From your comments, I see you are using an older version of the kernel. IN [later kernels](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h?v=2.6.35) , structure `net_device` still resides in `linux/netdevice.h` but there's no `get_stats` function pointer. Its changed into `ndo_get_stats` and it is now under another structure `net_device_ops`

So start using these new function pointers.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it keeps printing an error that says :
"implicit deceleration of function "get_stats" "
and yes, I've included the `<linux/netdevice.h>` library

Comment: In which file are you calling this?

Comment: what do you mean in which file? I'm calling the function in a kernel module I'm writing that is placed on my home folder

Comment: implicit declaration says that the compiler is not able to find the prototype of that function even in your header. In Kernel 3.3 I couldn't find anything like `get_stats`. The nearest I could find is `dev_get_stats`

Comment: `get_stats` is a member function in the struct `net_device`

Comment: at least that's what this page says :
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-17-sect-3

Comment: Are you using the same kernel as the book mentions? Also, I suspect that your header doesn contain the function pointer definition and hence it is treating it as a function and then the implicit function error

Comment: hmm, I'm using 2.6.35 while the books using 2.6.10... you're right the header I'm using doesn't have this struct the book is talking about

Comment: This is odd. the header file I have doesn't even look like the one you gave me the link to. mine only defines the `net_device` struct along with a small enum for port options and that's it. the one you gave me has TONS of other stuff.

Comment: You dont have sufficient privileges to enter into a chat and its not advicable for us to elaborate in comments section. For now, I would suggest you clearly downloading the same kernel as the book suggests from the same location ( if any suggestions on that ) and test your things. Once you become proficient you can upgrade to later kernels